# How to add JWT authentication to an MVC and Identity app to add support for native mobile apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an existing Core MVC app using Identity for authentication.  Without having to rewrite a lot of the app, I would like to be able to support native clients (iOS, Android, Flutter, etc).  I can add/adjust endpoints to serve JSON versus Views, but authentication is the sticking point.

How can an iOS user enter their username/password (stored in Identity User table) and receive back a JWT token, since the session cookie won't be particularly usable?

There's a lot of information out there, some of it multiple-years old.  Some of it doesn't use Identity.  For example, this is helpful: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET, but Rick isn't using Identity.

Another option is to insert something like Firebase into the middle, to serve tokens while authenticating to the underlying Identity User table.

Comment: _ASP.NET Core Identity_ does not provide a full set of IdP services (OIDC, SAML, etc - which is what you need for native-device client and delegated web-application authX) - for that you'll need something like IdentityServer4: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(option =>
        {
            //... your identity configurations
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                //... your JWT configurations
            };
        });
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
```

ApiController:

```
[HttpGet()]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: Adding Identity looks like:

`builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

How would this fit into your example?